# rebase not ignoring commits with same textual changes?

Tags: git, rebase

The `git rebase` manpage reads:

> If `<upstream>` is not specified, the upstream configured in `branch.<name>.remote` and `branch.<name>.merge` options will be used;
>
> [....]
>
> The commits that were previously saved into the temporary area are then reapplied to the current branch, one by one, in order. Note that any commits in `HEAD` which introduce the same textual changes as a commit in `HEAD..<upstream>` are omitted (i.e., a patch already accepted upstream with a different commit message or timestamp will be skipped).

And indeed, when I call `git rebase master` and there is a commit in `master` with the same textual changes as in my local branch's history, it is ignored. However, I've found that when I call `git rebase` without specifying `<upstream>` (which defaults to `master`), the output of `git rebase` seems show the same commit not being ignored.

#### Example

Here's an example to demonstrate this. Here is the git history:

```
A---B master
 \
  B' topic
```

`B` and `B'` introduce the same textual changes but have different commit messages. `topic` is set up to track `master`.

First, I rebase `topic` while suppling `<upstream>`:

```
$ git checkout topic
$ git rebase master
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
```

Nothing happens, as expected, since `B` and `B'` are diff-identical.

However, if I omit `<upstream>`:

```
$ git checkout topic
$ git rebase
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: Branch: topic
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
No changes -- Patch already applied.
```

It seems like git does not skip `B'` in the second output. Can someone please explain this discrepancy?

(I'm using git version 1.9.4)

Comment: Does `git cherry` detect that they are identical?  (or `git log --cherry` and friends).

Comment: You might want to browse the rebase source code, there are several paths through it and not all of them check for duplicates.  It seems like your second form is triggering that.

Comment: @AndrewC yes, `git cherry` reports the commits to be identical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is no longer the case (tested with latest Git 2.38.0). Here is a simple, fully-reproducible test case:

```
git init 26878037
cd 26878037
echo a > file
git add file
git commit -m 'initial commit'
git branch topic --track master
echo b >> file
git add file
git commit -m 'commit on master'
git checkout topic
echo b >> file
git add file
git commit -m 'commit on topic'
git rebase # defaults to upstream of topic, which is master
git log
```

Output of the `rebase` command:

```
warning: skipped previously applied commit d07369f
hint: use --reapply-cherry-picks to include skipped commits
hint: Disable this message with "git config advice.skippedCherryPicks false"
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/topic.
```

Log output:

```
a8002a0 (HEAD -> topic, master) commit on master
7443187 initial commit
```